# CdkDragAndDrop Angular observable datasource is reloading my component

Tags: angular, socket.io

My problem is that every time my subscription detects a new data, my entire kanban reloads and the column's scroll goes back to top.

[image: not working]

this is my html:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="selectedBoard"> 
  
<div class="root">
  <app-searcher> </app-searcher> 
  <div class="board">
    <div class=" h1 ml-3 boardHeader"> {{selectedBoard.title}} </div>

    <div class="board-wrapper">
      <div style="overflow-x:scroll" class="board-columns scrollable-content" cdkScrollable >
        
        <div cdkDropList
            cdkDropListOrientation="horizontal" class="board-columns"
            (cdkDropListDropped)="dropGrid($event)" 
            cdkDropListGroup
            >
        <div cdkDragLockAxis="x"  class="board-column" *ngFor="let column of selectedBoard.columns; let columnIndex = index" cdkDrag [cdkDragDisabled]="readOnlyPermissions">
          <div #colTitleEdit (click)="editColHeader(colTitleEdit,column)" class="column-title" cdkDragHandle>
            <form  class="form-input hidden"> 
              <input #colHeaderTitleInput (click)="stopPropagation($event)"(keydown.esc)="editColHeaderConfirm(colHeaderTitleInput.value,colTitleEdit,column)" (keyup.enter)="editColHeaderConfirm(colHeaderTitleInput.value,colTitleEdit,column)"  class="form-input" type="text" nbInput fullWidth fieldSize="medium" [(ngModel)]="column.headerText" name="listTitleEdit">
            </form>
            <span>{{ column.headerText }}</span>
            <span *ngIf="writePermissions" nbContextMenuTag="column-options" nbContextMenuTrigger="focus" nbContextMenuPlacement="right" [nbContextMenu]="columnOptions" (click)="colOptions($event,column)" class="float-right colOptions">
              <nb-icon  class="edit-icon" icon="more-horizontal-outline"></nb-icon>
            </span>
          </div>
         
          <div style="max-height:66vh; overflow-y:scroll" class="tasks-container " id="{{column._id}}" cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="column.cards"
          (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
         
            <div class="task" (click)="dialogOpen(column._id,card._id,column.headerText)" *ngFor="let card of column.cards; let indexOfCard = index" cdkDrag  [cdkDragStartDelay]="200" [cdkDragDisabled]="readOnlyPermissions" >
              <span *ngIf="!currentlyEditing && writePermissions" (click)="editCardTitle($event,card,columnIndex,indexOfCard)" class="edit-btn float-right hide">
                <nb-icon   class="edit-icon" icon="edit-outline"></nb-icon>
              </span>
              <div class="task-header"> 

                <app-labels (newLabels)="addLabel($event)" [labels]="card.labels"> </app-labels>
               
              </div>

              <div #cardOptionsMenu nbContextMenuTag="{{'card-options-'+columnIndex+'-'+indexOfCard}}" nbContextMenuTrigger="noop" nbContextMenuPlacement="right" [nbContextMenu]="cardOptions"  id="{{'cardBody-' + columnIndex +'-'+indexOfCard}}" class="task-body"> 
             


                <form *ngIf="currentlyEditing" class="form-input hidden"> 
                  <textarea (keydown.esc)="cancelEditCard($event,card,columnIndex,indexOfCard)" (clickOutside)="clickOutsideCancel(card,columnIndex,indexOfCard)" class="cardEdit" (click)="stopPropagation($event)" id="{{'cardTitle-'+columnIndex+'-'+indexOfCard}}" nbInput fullWidth fieldSize="large"  name="cardTitle"> </textarea>
              
                <div class="d-flex align-items-center pb-2 pt-2"> 
                  <button  type="submit" nbButton status="success" size="small" class="submit-btn shadow-3d  float-left"  (click)="editCardConfirm($event)"> <nb-icon icon="checkmark-outline"></nb-icon>Guardar</button>
                  <span (click)="cancelEditCard($event,card,columnIndex,indexOfCard)" class="float-left ml-2 cancelNewCard"> <nb-icon icon="close-outline"> </nb-icon> </span>
                </div>
              </form> 

                
                <span> {{ card.title }} </span>
                
              </div>  
             <div class="task-footer"> 
             <span style="font-size:12px; color:#5e6c84;" *ngIf="card.attachments > 0"> <nb-icon class="float-left" [config]="{icon: 'attach-outline', options: {'icon-font-size': '16px'}}">  </nb-icon>  {{card.attachments}} </span>
             <span  *ngIf="(card.cardInfo && card.cardInfo.FechaEntrega  && card.cardInfo.FechaEntrega.length>9) || card.expirationDate" class="info-badge" text="20 may"> <nb-icon icon="clock-outline"> </nb-icon>  {{card.cardInfo.FechaPedido | date:'dd MMM' }}</span>
             
             </div> 
            
             </div>
             
            
          </div>
         
        
          <div class="column-footer mt-2 pb-2"> 
            <button *ngIf="writePermissions" id="{{'addCardButton-' + columnIndex}}"  nbButton status="info" size="small" class="btn-shadow-3d shadow-3d "  (click)="showTitleInput(columnIndex)"> <nb-icon icon="plus"></nb-icon>Añadir una tarjeta</button>
            <div class="row"> 
            <div class="newCardInput col-12" id="{{'Title-' + columnIndex}}" style="display:none;"> 
             <form> 
                <input (keydown.esc)="cancelNewCard()" #cardTitleInput class="form-input" type="text" id="{{'cardTitle-' + columnIndex}}" nbInput fullWidth fieldSize="medium" placeholder="Título de la tarjeta"  name="title">
            
              <div class="d-flex align-items-center pb-2 pt-2"> 
                <button  type="submit" nbButton status="success" size="small" class="submit-btn shadow-3d  float-left"  (click)="addNewCard(cardTitleInput.value,columnIndex)"> <nb-icon icon="checkmark-outline"></nb-icon>Ok</button>
                <span (click)="cancelNewCard()" class="float-left ml-2 cancelNewCard"> <nb-icon icon="close-outline"> </nb-icon> </span>
              </div>
            </form> 
          </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
       <div *ngIf="writePermissions" #newColumnInput  (click)="addColumn()" class="add-new-col" >
      
        <form class="form-input hidden"> 
          <input #colTitleInput   class="form-input" type="text" nbInput fullWidth fieldSize="medium" placeholder="Título de la lista"  name="listTitle">
      
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center pb-2 pt-2"> 
          <button  type="submit" nbButton status="success" size="small" class="submit-btn shadow-3d  float-left"  (click)="addColumn(colTitleInput.value)"> <nb-icon icon="checkmark-outline"></nb-icon>Aceptar</button>
          <span (click)="cancelColumnAdd($event)" class="float-left ml-2 cancelNewCard"> <nb-icon icon="close-outline"> </nb-icon> </span>
        </div>
      </form> 
     
           <h3> <nb-icon icon="plus-outline"></nb-icon> Añadir otra lista </h3>
         
      </div>


      </div>
      
    </div>
    
  </div>

</div>
</div>

</ng-container>
```

and on my component.ts I have a method that listens a socket from my backend.

```js
 this.socketService.listenFromClient('kanbanToClient').subscribe((res:any) => {
      //con.sole.log(res)
      this.selectedBoard.columns = new Board(res).columns;
      this.kanbanService.currentBoard = this.selectedBoard;
      //con.sole.log(this.selectedBoard)
      
    })
```

I need the scroll to keep on the same position and prevent the label's animations. because those animations also are because is "reloaded"

Comment: Assuming the socket service returns the whole board, I'd guess that the reason you will be seeing everything reload is that you are replacing the entire board and not only what's changed. I can't really offer more than that without seeing more code. If you could knock together a StackBlitz I will take a look.

Comment: Could I have a function that compares the current board and the incoming board and only replace the changes? any clue of how can I acchieve this?

Comment: Yes, of course you could. I can't really give you an answer without knowing your data structure. I assume the cards will have a unique ID and also some sort of relation to the columns they're in. You will be able to then tell which cards in the new list have moved column compared to the old list according to their column ID. Again, I don't know your data structure so can't help more. 

A good starting place would be to search on StackOverflow for comparing and finding the differences in two lists of objects.

Comment: Try adding a trackBy function to your ngfor loops and track by a unique I'd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Jason White said

> Try adding a trackBy function to your ngfor loops and track by a
> unique I'd.

I did this and the problem is solved. Thank you so much.